# LDAPS DirectorySearcher.FindOne throws exception

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to validate a user using a secured LDAP query. My code throws an exception while calling

```
SearchResult result = search.FindOne;
```

Complete code:

```
public bool IsValidUser(object username)
{
    isValidUser = false;

    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://office:636/", "myaccount", "mypassword");
        AD.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(AD);
        search.SearchRoot = AD;
        search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        if (username == DBNull.Value == false & username != "")
        {
            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if ((result == null))
                isValidUser = false;
            else
                isValidUser = true;
        }
        else
            isValidUser = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // log(ex);
    }

    return isValidUser;
}
```

If I do not provide port number 636, it will work fine but I do not think then the LDAP is done under secured network.

Comment: And what would that exception be?

Comment: If you want to use 636 you will need to have LDAPS enabled on the domain controller

Comment: These are exception messages.
Unknown error (0x80005000)

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

Comment: I have another Search method, which does not throw error, only difference in code * after username in search filter 
 <pre>searchfilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" & searchParm & "*))"</pre>

Comment: I asked my IT , he says, we do have ssl installed in our DC

Comment: I provide full ad path like "LDAP://office:636/DC=mycompany,DC=com and it did not throw any exception. But I do not have any idea. I would like to read resource that can be helpful and I can give knowledge of what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help someone (or future me) - the domain controller can get corrupted sometimes, if it does it makes it impossible to use secure port 636, try to change to non secure port 389 to see if that's the case.

See also: ["The server is not operational" domain controller configuration error when you configure a server by using Server Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2738697/the-server-is-not-operational-domain-controller-configuration-error-wh)